# Call $.ajax malfunctioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a ajax call, but server side code is not hit. Instead control goes to javascript file included in project. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddEmployee() 
    {
        debugger;
        // jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.support.cors = true;
        var Product = new Object();
        Product.ID = 10;
        Product.Name = "kRISH";
        Product.Price = "23";
        Product.Category = "AS";
        // console.log(JSON.stringify({ Name: "kRISH", Price: "23", Category: "AS" }));
        var json_text = JSON.stringify(Product,null,2);
        **$.ajax**
        ({
            url: 'http://localhost:62310/api/products',
            type: 'POST',
            data: json_text,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) { WriteResponse(data); },
            error: function (x, y, z) 
            {
                $('#contentProgress').popup("close");
                alert(x.responseText + " " + x.status);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: and where is `AddEmployee` being called?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser's debug console? Where does the control go - somewhere that catches exceptions? Or the line after the AddEmployee call - this is an asynchronous AJAX method, you wouldn't expect the success or error to fire immediately anyway even on success.

Comment: What does *"control goes to javascript file"* mean?

Comment: Another thought: is this potentially a CORS issue? Is this code not hosted on localhost:62310 and are you using a CORS-aware browser? Watch the network tab in the debugger to see if it issues an OPTIONS request to your server and then stops.

Comment: Yeah i think it is an CROS issue. it does stops after calling post request to server.suggest me some tips.

Answer (score 1):

Is the url correct, why are we not using the relative url here. Can you please try this

```
  $.ajax('http://localhost:62310/api/products', {
        type: "post",
        data: json_text,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
  });
```

Comment: He's added `cache: false` in case it's using a cached value rather than making the AJAX request to your server.

Comment: Does this work fine for you? If not then what does the alert show.

Comment: No it does not works neither any error message pop ups even i have added some alert message in error block of the ajax call.do calling $.Ajax requires some additional installation???

Comment: You should have JQuery loaded in the page. If you don't have done that already, try to load from CDN for now.
`<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1"></script>`

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can you put breakpoint on error callback. Also, can you change the url to `~/api/Products`